# Why does Agatha buy the book titled The Number 23 for her husband?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-number-23

Agatha buys the book (titled The Number 23 written by Topsy Kretts) for her husband Walter as a birthday present. Why does she choose this book? Is it a coincidence? Doesn't she know about the past of her husband?

Comment: I'd like to pile on this question with another, don't they recall the two of them met right after his getting out of the asylum? Or do they really get together at this time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

She merely bought the book for him as she felt he would be very interested in it, having just skimmed through it herself.  She did not (nor did Walter, at this point) know anything about his past or that he actually wrote the book.

It is essentially a  <strike>plot device</strike> coincidence.

Comment: But Agatha did know his past. It doesn't make sense why she would buy him this book and not know it was him